# Does Mass Effect 3 use background balancing?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Some games allow balance adjustments to be made without issuing a title update or patch. Monday Night Combat is one example of this ([Source](http://www.shacknews.com/article/65056/monday-night-combat-supports-background)). This is especially desirable on Xbox 360, because the certification process for title updates can take months and cost developers a large sum of money.

[This thread](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/343/index/9544143) on BSN lists the balance changes that are slated for Mass Effect 3 multiplayer. **Will these balance changes take place behind the scenes (immediately), or will they only occur after a title update or patch is issued?**

It seems to me like the easiest way to know for sure would be for an Xbox 360 player with a Quarian Infiltrator to test whether the Sabotage changes have taken place already. I would test this myself but I haven't unlocked that race yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems so.

The thread you mention actually states the listed changes are already implemented. Since there are no patches released that means all changes are done server-side only.

Comment: It appears that you are correct, the changes in the patch notes have been applied but no title updates or patches have been issued.